# What can human beings make out of the restrict qualifier?

Tags: c, c99, keyword, restrict-qualifier

If I got the C99 `restrict` keyword right, qualifying a pointer with it is a promise made that the data it references won't be modified behind the compiler's back through aliasing.

By contrast, the way I understand the `const` qualifier is as compiler-enforced documentation that a given object won't be modified behind the back of a human being writing code. The compiler might get a hint as a side effect, but as a programmer I don't really care.

In a similar way, would it be appropriate to consider a `restrict` qualifier in a function prototype as a requirement that the user ensures exclusive access ("avoid aliasing", or maybe something stronger) for the duration of the call? Should it be used as "documentation"?

Also, is there something to understand in the fact that `restrict` qualifies a pointer rather than the data it points to (as `const` does) ?

EDIT: I originally believed that `restrict` could have implications with threaded code, but this seems wrong so I remove references to threads from the question to avoid confusing readers.

Comment: Well there's a C keyword I've never heard of before...

Comment: @Nick Bedford: It's in C99, not C89.  So, only ten years a standard keyword...

Comment: @Jeremie: any idea what a volatile restricted pointer means?  I think it is the absence of the volatile that means a restricted pointer won't be modified behind the compiler's back.  Restricted 'more or less' means that there isn't a way for the parameters to the function to overlap in memory.  Check the discussion of restict in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485505 and links from there (the links to a Python PEP and to Cell Project documents).

Comment: @Jonathan: A `volatile restrict` pointer has to be accessed exactly once for each time that's indicated by the source code, but the compiler can reorder those accesses with access to non-volatile variables.  If it is simply `volatile` but not also `restrict`, it not only has to read the target every time, but it has to wait to do so until after writing any other variable that could alias the target.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best 'intuition' to have about the restrict keyword is that its a guarantee (by the programmer to the compiler) that, for the lifetime of the pointer, memory accessed via that pointer will ONLY be accessed via that pointer and not via another pointer or reference or global address. So its important that its on a pointer as its a property of both the pointer and the memory, tying the two together until the pointer goes out of scope.

Answer (score 23):

Chris Dodd has the correct description of the keyword. In certain platforms it can be very important for performance reasons, because it lets the compiler know that once it has loaded data through that pointer onto a register, it need not do so again. Without this guarantee, the compiler must reload the data through a pointer every time any other possibly-aliasing pointer is written through, which can cause a serious pipeline stall called a [load-hit-store](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3687/sponsored_feature_common_.php).

`const` and `restrict` are different concepts, and it is not the case that `const` implies `restrict`. All `const` says is that you will not write through that pointer *within the scope of that function*. A `const` pointer may still be aliased. For example consider:

```
int foo( const int *a, int * b )
{
   *b *= 2;
   return *a + *b; // induces LHS: *a must be read back immediately
                   // after write has cleared the store queue
}
```

While you cannot directly write to `a` in this function, it would perfectly legal for you to call foo like:

```
int x = 3;
foo( &x, &x );  // returns 12
```

`restrict` is a different guarantee: a promise that `a != b` in all calls to `foo()`.

I've [written about the `restrict` keyword and its performance implications at length](http://assemblyrequired.crashworks.org/2008/07/08/load-hit-stores-and-the-__restrict-keyword/), and [so has Mike Acton](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/05/demystifying-the-restrict-keyword.html).   Although we talk about a specific in-order PowerPC, the load-hit-store problem exists on the x86 as well, but the x86's out-of-order execution makes that stall harder to isolate in a profile.

And just to emphasize: this is *not* an arcane or premature optimization, if you care about performance at all. `restrict` can lead to really significant speedups if used correctly.

Comment: I don't think the example necessarily results in `*b` being read back immediately (gcc with -O3 does what you'd want it to: reads a and b off the stack into edx and ecx respectively, then does `mov (%ecx),%eax`, `add %eax,%eax`, `mov %eax,(%exc)`, `mov (%edx),%ecx`, `pop %ebp`, `add %ecx,%eax`, `ret`). If `*a` were also modified in the function of course that would be a different story.

Comment: mov %eax,(%exc), mov (%edx),%ecx is the load-hit-store right there. I did mean *a instead of *b though.

Comment: So that stalls even if ecx and edx have different values? I didn't know that. Adding restrict doesn't change the output from gcc 3 at all, it doesn't even load from edx/a any earlier. So it seems that with that compiler, the LHS is inevitable no matter what you do.

Comment: It stalls (inside the CPU pipeline) if edx and ecx happen to be the same value. It doesn't if the one load doesn't hit the other store. That's why LHS are insidious: you cannot see them from looking at the code inside a function; the problem comes in the aliasing of the parameters you were passed.    What restrict *should* do in this case is mov (%ecx),%eax ; mov (%edx),%ebx ; add %ebx, %ebx ; add %eax, %ebx ; ret .    And yeah, GCC does emit more than its share of WTFs.

Comment: The more serious example of the problem would be if I wrote eg `*a += 3` before the `*b *= 2`; in that case a load would inevitably have to hit a store *even if the pointers did not alias* because the compiler would have to load back *a after touching *b; and *a had just been written.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense. Sure, if they're the same value there's a stall, but then if they're the same value then you couldn't use restrict either. I confess I was a bit surprised that the load from edx wasn't started sooner with restrict, but I try to assume that x86 pipelining is Much Smarter Than Me nowadays. So when the values are different, I'd be surprised if there's a full load stall (waiting for eax) at `add eax,eax`, and then another one (for ecx) at `add ecx,eax` that doesn't even start until the previous one has finished. But maybe I'm too optimistic.

Comment: Compilers and pipelines are really much less clever than people seem to assume. In particular, if you load from an address that has a pending store, the CPU will usually have to throw out the whole pipeline and start over when the store has finished. Some x86s are better at this because of store forwarding, but an in-order PowerPC is definitely not; it just stops dead until the write bounces off the cache. And there's not many instructions that the x86 could reorder to happen while it's waiting for the read: everything afterwards is dependent on it!

Comment: If it was just simple assignment, would this still apply? For example, something like `void f(const char *ac) { str = ac; }`. If `ac` and `str` were aliased, it wouldn't make a difference, right?

Comment: @someguy In that case, probably not. It's writing and reading *through* a pointer that can induce the stall.

Answer (score 8):

Most of what you know is wrong!

const does **not** guarantee that something won't change behind the compiler's back. All it does is stop **you** from writing to that spot. Something else might still be able to write to that location though, so the compiler canNOT assume it's constant.

As others have said, the restrict qualifier is about aliasing. In fact, during the first round of C standardization, there was a proposal for a "noalias" keyword. Unfortunately, the proposal was fairly poorly written -- it prompted the one and only time the Dennis Ritchie got involved during that process, when he wrote a letter that said something to the effect that "noalias must go. This is not open to negotiation."

Needless to say, 'noalias' didn't become part of C. When it came time to try again, the proposal was written enough better that restrict was included in the standard -- and even though noalias would probably have been a more meaningful name for it, that name was so tainted that I doubt anybody even considered trying to use it.

In any case, the primary intent of restrict is to tell the compiler that there will not be an alias of this item. One reason for this is to allow things to be stored in registers temporarily. For example, consider something like:

```
void f(int *a, int *b, int *c) { 
    for (int i=0; i<*a; i++)
        *b += c[i];
}
```

The compiler really wants to put i in a register, and load *a into a register, so when it comes time to decide whether to execute another iteration of the loop, it just compares the values in those to registers to each other. Unfortunately, it can't do that -- if somebody who used this function was completely insane, and called it with a==b, every time it writes to *b inside the loop, that new value is also the value of *a -- so it has to read *a from memory at every iteration of the loop, **just in case** whoever called it was completely insane. Using restrict tells the compiler it can generate code assuming that a and b will always be distinct, so writing to *a will never change *b (or vice versa).

Comment: actually, values are not allowed to change behind the compilers back at all, whether `const` is present or not; if values do change, you'll have to add the `volatile` qualifier

Comment: Yes and no -- volatile means you want the compiler to generate code that takes account of the possibility that it'll change behind your back.

Comment: I wonder how "noalias" would have worked, and what aspects Ritchie most objected to?  I would think C would have benefited from a "_cacheable(lvalue)" directive that would specify that any reads of the lvalue or lvalues derived from it within the statement may be arbitrarily sequenced to any earlier time within the statement, and writes may be arbitrarily sequenced at any later time within the statement.  Given global declaration `int x;`, and within a function `int * restrict px=&x; foo(*px); foo(*px);` a compiler could load `x` once into a callee-saved register, pass it to `foo`, and then...

Comment: ...pass it to `foo` again without having to reload it, but unless a compiler recognized that `px` was constant and recignized the effects of `restrict`, the generated machine code for the latter approach could end up slower than it would have been if `x` were simply loaded twice.  A `_cacheable(x)` directive could have been easier for humans to read and for the compiler to process.

Answer (score 6):

Your understanding is largely correct. The `restrict` qualifier simply states that the data accessed by a so-qualified pointer is *only* accessed by that exact pointer. It applies to reads as wells as writes.

The compiler doesn't care about concurrent threads, it wasn't going to generate code any differently, and you may clobber your own data as you like. But it does need to know what pointer operations may change what global memory.

`Restrict` also carries with it an API warning to humans that a given function is implemented with the assumption of unaliased parameters.

No locking by the user is necessary as far as the compiler is concerned. It only wants to make sure it correctly reads data that was *supposed* to be clobbered, by code *the compiler was supposed to generate*, in case there is no `restrict` qualifier. Adding `restrict` frees it from that concern.

Finally, note that the compiler is likely to already be analyzing possible aliasing based on data types, at the higher optimization levels, so `restrict` is important mostly for functions with multiple pointers to the same type of data. You can take a lesson from this subject and make sure that any deliberate aliasing you do is done via a `union`.

We can see `restrict` in action:

```
void move(int *a, int *b) {     void move(int *__restrict a, int *__restrict b) {
    a[0] = b[0];                    a[0] = b[0];
    a[1] = b[0];                    a[1] = b[0];
}                               }
    movl    (%edx), %eax            movl    (%edx), %edx
    movl    %eax, (%ecx)            movl    %edx, (%eax)
    movl    (%edx), %eax            movl    %edx, 4(%eax)
    movl    %eax, 4(%ecx)
```

In the right column, with `restrict`, the compiler did not need to reread `b[0]` from memory . It was able to read `b[0]` and keep it in register `%edx`, and then just store the register twice to memory. In the left column, it didn't know if the store to `a` may have changed `b`.

Comment: const does not imply restrict.

Comment: Of course not, but if it's known to the compiler to be `const` then presumably the compiler doesn't have to worry about scheduling stores to it.

Comment: It needn't worry about scheduling stores, but the pointer may still be aliased by something else, and so the compiler still has to reread through the const pointer any time any other pointer is stored through.

Answer (score 1):

Someone more familiar with the standard could probably give a better answer, but I'll give it a shot.

"Data won't be modified behind the compiler's back" sounds more like the opposite of "volatile" to me.

"const" means the data won't be modified in front of the programmer; that is, she can't modify the data through the signifier marked as "const" (I write "signifier" because in `int const *pi`, the name `pi` isn't const, but `*pi` is). The data might be modifiable via another signifier (non-const data can be passed to a function as const data, after all).

That "restrict" qualifies pointers is the key. Pointers are the only way to alias data in C, so they're the only way that you can access some piece of data via two different names. "restrict" is all about limiting data access to one access path.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an example from an *extremely* narrow domain, but Altera's Nios II platform is a soft-core microcontroller that you can customize within an FPGA.  Then, within the C source code for that micro, you can use a C-to-hardware tool to speed up inner loops using custom hardware, rather than in software.

In there, use of the `__restrict__` keyword (which is the same as C99's `restrict`) allows the C2H tool to properly optimize the hardware acceleration of pointer operation *in parallel* instead of sequentially.  At least in this case, the `restrict` is simply *not* meant for human consumption.  See also [Sun's page on `restrict`](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/cc_restrict.html), where the first line says

> Using the `restrict` qualifier appropriately in C programs may allow the compiler to produce significantly faster executables.

If anyone's interested in reading more on C2H, [this PDF](http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/nios2/edh_ed51005.pdf) discusses optimizing C2H results.  The section on `__restrict__` is on page 20.